# CVS in Eclipse showing multiple revision numbers

Tags: eclipse, cvs

CVS is showing multiple revisions numbers at the end of my file names. Any idea what is going on here and whether I should be worried?

[image: CVS problem]

Comment: What do you have configured for `File Decorations` in `Preferences > Team > CVS > Label Decorations` on the `Text Decorations` tab?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how do you sync your files with your CVS. In my case I do sync externally[meaning, not from eclipse] in such case you can select all your projects > Team [on right menu] > Disconnect >do not delete CVS metadata info in next window.

Answer (score 0):

CVS (like RCS, but unlike many other systems like SVN and Git) tracks the revision history of each file independently. In SVN, for example, a given version number applies to the entire repository. In CVS, each file has its own independent history and current version number. Having different version numbers for different files is perfectly normal.